# Python pandas, data binning a column by X size

Tags: python, pandas

When fetching data for an orderbook I get it in this format

```
    Price    Size
--------------------
0   8549.61  0.107015
1   8549.32  0.100000
2   8549.31  0.060000
3   8548.66  0.013950
4   8548.65  0.064791
... ... ...
995 8401.40  0.313921
996 8401.19  0.767512
997 8401.17  0.001721
998 8401.10  0.166487
999 8401.03  0.002235

1000 rows × 2 columns
```

Is there a way to combine the values of price every $10 and the size would be a sum of that range?

For example

```
    Price   Size
--------------------
0   8550    0.107015
1   8560    0.100000
2    870    0.060000
3   8580    0.013950
```

I was looking at binning but that gave me weird results, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain more clearly how the given inputs map to the given outputs? Maybe a smaller but more representative sample of your data would make a better [mcve]?

Comment: _I was looking at binning but that gave me weird results_ Can you expand on that?

Comment: Sorry for the bad example, Lets say you have an orderbook on an exchange for example BTC/USDT

You have an orderbook with data, and I would like to bin the data every 10$ so to say

So all orders from 4000$-4010$ would be added up into 1 row
I hope this makes it a bit more clear!

About the binning, I got it into bins that were in a strange size and they didn't add up the other collumns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Pandas` to do this.

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(str)
#determine the length inorder to modify the significant digit
len_str=len(str(int(float(df['Price'][0]))))

df['binned'] = df.groupby(df.Price.str[0:len_str-1])['Size'].transform('sum')
df['column'] = df.Price.str[0:len_str-1]+'0'

df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['column', 'binned'])[['column','binned']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't think of doing it like that thanks!